# iOS 4 wireless distribution and new devices

Tags: iphone

I'm looking into the new wireless distribution process in iOS 4 to deploy my apps within my company. I had one small question about this:

When there's a new device in the company and I update the Provisioning Profile, do I have to rebuild the app using this profile each time?

In other words: do I have to rebuild the app each time there's a new employee (or a new device), or can I just add the device's UDID to the provisioning profile and distribute the same .ipa-file?

I hope the latter, otherwise adding new devices becomes pretty time-consuming...

thanks for the help,

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provisioning profile can also be distributed via the website.

You can add new devices to that one, and users only have to install this new provisioning profile, if the current profile which is part of the .ipa file doesn't contain their devices. The provisioning profile has to be installed before installing the .ipa file in that case.

This works, until the provisioning profile expires, then you'll also have to provide a new .ipa build generated with the latest provisioning profile.

There is an open source framework with a server component in PHP5, which handles the website automaticall, you only need to place the files into a subfolder according to the documentation: https://github.com/TheRealKerni/Hockey
(Note: this project was started by myself)

Comment: Does the provisioning profile have to be installed via iTunes? Or can it be downloaded from the device too?

Comment: It can be installed from the device too. Directly from a website.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to rebuild the app, but you have to install the new provisioning profile on the device before you can install the app.

This should be no problem if you also use configuration profiles which you also can install using the iphone configuration utility or you might put the provisioning profile on your intranet for easy updating.

Comment: Can I add the provisioning profile to the website where my ipa resides, so new users can first download the provisioning profile and then the application? Or does the provisioning profile have to be installed through iTunes?

Comment: You can put them on the website and install them from there. (At least with ios 4 devices).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about simply re-distributing the same file, but you could consider automating the builds. Alternatively, there's a .mobileprovision in the bundle (not the compressed .ipa file, but the build folder) which may work if you replaced it with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mobileiron.com/ has a solution I am looking at for enterprise. Supports Android, Blackberry and iOS. You'll want to push profiles unbundled from the app, otherwise you would need to build a separate app for each device.